# how to set one continuous background image for multiple elements

Tags: html, css

I've been wrecking my brain trying to figure this out. is there any way to set one background image in css for multiple elements? I have a square-ish speech bubble, made with regular css, the triangle made with the border technique, but i want an background image to fill them both so it looks like a cut out all together.

I dont know any other way to design a solid shape using html/css other than squares and rectangles. If i could create a speech bubble as one solid shape, then giving it a bg would be simple lol.

I was wondering about html5's drawing capabilites, but im not sure...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just do this as an image altogether? Sounds less painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: No, there's no option to do what you want. But if you wanna do spech bubbles, you can check any of these links:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

http://konigi.com/tools/css-tooltips-and-speech-bubbles

http://desandro.com/resources/css-speech-bubble-icon/

Comment: Also checkout the CSS3 image-border property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp